# lualatex and pdflatex: lmr and cmr

Tags: font-encodings

Switching pdflatex to lualatex gives the following warning message with some rare font packages (see the MWE):

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LPH/lmr/m/n' undefined (Font) using `LPH/cmr/m/n'
instead (Font) for symbol `PHplumedHead' on input line 9.
```

I understand the warning, but can someone briefly explain why this warning is not given with pdflatex? Does lualatex use cmr (Computer Modern Roman) as default instead of lmr (Latin Modern Roman) as opposed to pdflatex?

How to get rid of the warnings with lualatex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phaistos} % font package defining \PHplumedHead below
\begin{document}
\PHplumedHead
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `minimal` for examples: it is not suitable. Both engines use CMR by default. Usually, you want to use `fontspec` with LuaLaTeX, though, which switches the default to LMR. EDIT: Apparently it uses LMR even without `fontspec`.

Comment: @cfr: fixed the `minimal`. Adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` does not remove the warning tho.

Comment: No. It won't. The question is whether you want to be using standard font encodings with LuaTeX. If you do, can't you just ignore the warning? It's only a warning.

Comment: It is the other way round: the default family of pdflatex is cmr, and as the font exist it works, but with lualatex the default family is lmr. Add `\makeatletter\show\f@family` to see it.

Comment: @cfr: I know this is a limited, silly little question. I have ignored the warning for several years. Now that I am on my summer leave I finally had time to gain some understanding and try to rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the warning as soon as the default family is not `cmr`, whatever engine you use.

You can get rid of the warning by using `substitutefont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phaistos} % font package defining \PHplumedHead below
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{LPH}{\familydefault}{cmr}

\begin{document}

\PHplumedHead

\end{document}
```

***Don't*** do it with `pdflatex` if you don't load some font package that sets a new default font.

Much preferable would be if the `phaistos` package didn't try and define the font to belong to the `cmr` family.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{phaistos}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{phaistos}{m}{n}{ <-> phaistos }{}

\newcommand{\newphaistossymbol}[2]{\newcommand#1{\phaistossymbol{#2}}}
\newcommand{\phaistossymbol}[1]{{\usefont{U}{phaistos}{m}{n}\symbol{#1}}}

\newphaistossymbol{\PHpedestrian}{"41}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHplumedHead}{"42}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHtattooedHead}{"43}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHcaptive}{"44}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHchild}{"45}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHwoman}{"46}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHhelmet}{"47}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHgaunlet}{"48}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHtiara}{"49}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHarrow}{"4A}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHbow}{"4B}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHshield}{"4C}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHclub}{"4D}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHmanacles}{"4E}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHmattock}{"4F}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHsaw}{"50}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHlid}{"51}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHboomerang}{"52}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHcarpentryPlane}{"53}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHdolium}{"54}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHcomb}{"55}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHsling}{"56}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHcolumn}{"57}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHbeehive}{"58}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHship}{"59}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHhorn}{"5A}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHhide}{"61}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHbullLeg}{"62}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHcat}{"63}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHram}{"64}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHeagle}{"65}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHdove}{"66}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHtunny}{"67}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHbee}{"68}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHplaneTree}{"69}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHvine}{"6A}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHpapyrus}{"6B}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHrosette}{"6C}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHlily}{"6D}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHoxBack}{"6E}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHflute}{"6F}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHgrater}{"70}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHstrainer}{"71}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHsmallAxe}{"72}
\newphaistossymbol{\PHwavyBand}{"73}

\begin{document}

\PHplumedHead

\end{document}
```

The above will work independently of the engine, with no warning.

Comment: Ah, this gave me the idea to go see the `.sty` file of the package. From there I replaced all the `DeclareFont`-commands with `cmr` with `lmr`. Perhaps not preferable, but now I understand more about how the fonts are defined.

Comment: @Mappi I think it was a very bad idea of the package author to define the font as belonging to the `cmr` package. I added an independent version that will produce no warning and the same output.